# PHP short tags echo method (without the equal to)

Tags: php, if-statement, echo, shorttags

Very simple:

So... That is working perfectly

```
<?=($A>9)?":)":":(";?>
```

Now... How can I say the same exact thing without `=` **AND** without `echo` ?

iow... I want to use that shortcut technique inside php code in between other php lines.

so this is NOT the correct syntax but just to get the idea more clearly...

```
<?

$A=50;

($A>9)?":)":":(";

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could simply not use PHP. If you want that text to be there without PHP's syntax, you don't have to use it in the first place.

Just include

```
($A>9)?":)":":(";
```

directly in the source text.